# ASP.NET VB JQuery DIM a div based on variable value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I need to 'dim' a div based on a session object value.

Declared session object as a module in `Global.asax.vb`

```
Module SelectedItem
    Public SelItemID As Integer
End Module
```

Now I need to check if that variable has value, and if it doesn't several divs that make up my menu should be dimmed. Now `menuButton1` should always be available, and others should be dimmed if the mentioned variable doesn't have value.

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menuButton1">
    </div>
    <div class="menuButton2"> //should be dimmed if SelItemID = null
    </div>
    <div class="menuButton3"> //should be dimmed if SelItemId = null
    </div>
</div>
```

If it has value, they should look normal. I realize this should be quite easy with JQuery but I'm clueless how to do it combined with VB.

Some more info. I'm showing `SelItemID` in a label on page. Maybe I could check that label for value or something?

Please help if possible.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Ok so I've thought of a simpler way for this just need a bit of help to see it through.

```
<%IIf(lbSelItem.Text = "No Item Selected.", "<a href='Default.aspx'>&nbsp;My Item&nbsp;</a>", "My Item")%>
```

Basically I want it to show regular text if true and link if false. Note: label `lbSelItem` is showing `"No Item Selected"` string value of no item is selected. Issue with this code is that it doesn't show anything. Neither the link nor the text.

Comment: VB is run on the server, jQuery is run on the client. They are completely separate. In your server code you could check the value of `SelItemID` and add a class to items that need to be dimmed, or on the client you can check the value that you have inserted into the page and add a class to the items.

Comment: Could you give me some sample code for VB class adding? And how would that class look like?

Comment: it's not a VB class, it's a css class, you would just add another one in the `class=` attribute in your html. Also, your `SelItemID` will never be null because you declared it as an Integer (not a nullable int)

Comment: I understand just written plainly for simplicity. It will be either 0 or not, also I do understand it's a css class, just never have altered css through VB so any sample would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what your issue is then... you do know how to use the `<% %>` tags, right? If all you need to do is modify your html based on the value of a variable, that is one of the most basic tasks that any novice should be able to accomplish, and there are thousands of tutorials on the internet that can teach you.

Comment: I guess I do have issues with VB and I do know to use `<% %>` tags, but using Razor lately made me bit dull to VB... That's why I wanted to ask for advice here. This is what Stack is for, I guess :)
Thanks for the info, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Feeling so silly now. For reference if someone perhaps gets a brain-glitch like me.

In these cases just use this.

```
<% If lbSelProj.Text = "No Items Selected." Then %>
    My Items                                             // this will show if not selected
<%Else%>
    <a href="Default.aspx" >&nbsp;My Item&nbsp;</a>      // this will show if selected
<% End If%>
```

Pretty simple eh... Thank you, MrOBrian for making me realize my mistake.